# Insert wordpress tags below posts via functions.php

Tags: php, posts, functions, tags

I'm in the process of building my own Wordpress theme from scratch and my knowledge of PHP is limited. What I'm trying to do is insert tags below each post. I can do this by inserting code into my single.php file but I want to do this through the `functions.php` file.

I have already inserted an author box below each post through the functions.php file. I got the code for that somewhere online and I would like to do the same thing with the tags.

Here is the author box code in my `functions.php` file.

```
function get_author_bio($content='') {
    global $post;
    $post_author_name=get_the_author_meta("display_name");
    $post_author_description=get_the_author_meta("description");
    $html="<div class='author-box'>\n";
    $html.="<h5 class='author'>About the author</h5>\n";
    $html.="<div class='author-entry'>\n";
    $html.="<img width='100' height='100' class='avatar' src='http://www.gravatar.com/avatar.php?gravatar_id=".md5(get_the_author_email()). "&default=".urlencode

($GLOBALS['defaultgravatar'])."&size=80&r=PG' alt='PG'/>\n";
    $html.="<h6 class='author-name'>".$post_author_name."</h6>\n";
    $html.= "<p>".$post_author_description."</p>\n";
    $html.="</div>\n";
    $html.="</div>\n";
    $content .= $html;
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'get_author_bio');
```

It works great and it allows me to add HTML elements for easy CSS styling. I want something similar for the tags. Cab anyone help me?

Comment: You already worked out the basics. What exactly is giving you trouble with tags?

Comment: The problem is that I do not know how to insert tags via the functions.php file.

Comment: Well, yes, but that isn't much detail. Have you tried [the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_tags)?

Comment: I have tried the codex but it's confusing. What I'm trying to do is insert tags below each of the posts. I can do it by inserting <?php the_tags(); ?> into the single.php file but I need to have it in the functions.php file.

Comment: I have written a simple case answer for you. See below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is add tags to the post body without writing them into the theme templates, all you really need to do is:

```
add_filter(
  'the_content',
  function($content) {
    return $content.get_the_tag_list();
  }
);
```

See [`get_the_tag_list()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tag_list) for arguments. That, by the way, [is basically what the `the_tags()` function does](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-includes/category-template.php#L1193).

However, there are other ways to do it and those ways may be better depending upon you exact requirements. As written, your question is pretty light on detail.